# How to make plotly charts adjust to page width using rmarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, plotly, hugo, blogdown

I have an R blog post with some leaflet and plotly figures. I can set `width = "100%"` in the `leaflet()` function, and the leaflet map will change shape as I resize my browser window (or view on mobile). I've tried the same `width = "100%"` in `plot_ly()`, but the plot doesn't resize for smaller windows and requires horizontal scrolling.

Any ideas? I'm using blogdown/hugo if that is helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the chunk option:

````
```{r, out.width='100%'}
````