# Get plotly in an Rmarkdown file to occupy all horizontal space in HTML

Tags: r, plotly, r-markdown

I'm trying to use `plotly` in an Rmarkdown file, but the plots all get rendered in HTML without occupying the available horizontal space and therefore feel very cramped. I've tried the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59063099/2175231) (`out.width='100%'`), but to no effect:

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output: html_notebook
---

[filler text]

```{r, out.width='100%'}
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(plotly))

plotly::plot_ly() %>%
  add_lines(
    x = seq(1:1000),
    y = runif(1000)
  ) %>%
  layout(
    autosize = TRUE
  )
```
````

This gets rendered in HTML (on Chrome) as:

[image]

I've also tried calling `knitr::opts_chunk$set(out.width = "100%")` directly (in its own chunk before the plot), but to no effect.

Following @Axeman's comment, I also tried setting `output: html_document`. This works as far as getting `plotly` to fill the horizontal space, but disables table pagination. So my actual use-case, which includes tables with hundreds of lines, becomes unusable, demanding endless scrolling past those tables.

How should this be done?

Comment: This seems to be linked to using `html_notebook`, if I use `html_document` as output it works as expected for me.

Comment: @Axeman indeed, that works for me, too. But my actual case also includes tables with hundreds of lines, and using `html_document` seems to disable the table pagination, so the document basically becomes 99% tables and 1% other content.

Answer (score 0):

````
```{r set-options, echo=FALSE, cache=FALSE}
options(width = 10000)
```
````

only made it as wide as the margins that displays the code chunk, but like mentioned in the comments, only seemed to work when knitted to `html_document`.