# How to make charts in Rmarkdown mobile-responsive?

Tags: html, r, d3.js, r2d3

I'm using the r2d3 library in R to insert some d3 charts in an RMarkdown.  I'm knitting to HTML.  My issue is that I can't seem to figure out how to make the RMarkdown mobile-responsive (I want the charts to resize dynamically).

This is a simple example:

**d3 script (test.js):**

```
// !preview r2d3 data=c(0.3, 0.6, 0.8, 0.95, 0.40, 0.20)
//
// r2d3: https://rstudio.github.io/r2d3
//

var barHeight = Math.ceil(height / data.length);

svg.selectAll('rect')
  .data(data)
  .enter().append('rect')
    .attr('width', function(d) { return d * width; })
    .attr('height', barHeight)
    .attr('y', function(d, i) { return i * barHeight; })
    .attr('fill', 'steelblue');
```

**R-Markdown:**

```
library(r2d3)
r2d3(data = c(0.3, 0.6, 0.8, 0.95, 0.40, 0.20),
     script = "X:/public/Moss/D3 Practice/test.js",
     d3_version = "3")
```

In the R Studio preview pane, the chart auto-resizes just fine.  In the HTML doc, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this helped me:

[How to make plotly charts adjust to page width using rmarkdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59063099/how-to-make-plotly-charts-adjust-to-page-width-using-rmarkdown)

I just set the chunk in RMarkdown to be:

```
{r out.width='100%', fig.height=3}
```

Seems to apply to d3 charts .

Comment: You could maybe explain how to apply the answer you found to your question.